# Lemp vs Nginx as reverse proxy in Lamp

Tags: apache, nginx, web, server

I wonder if there is any benchmark or practical advice between LEMP and Nginx as reverse proxy in LAMP model.

I have been searching for technical advices and the main articles i came across are comparisons beteen nginx and apache and between LAMP and LEMP. In sort nginx is supposed to be better for static content and apache for dynamic content and for this reason nginx is used as a reverse proxy on a LAMP stack to combine the advantages of each technology. However LEMP is also quite popular but I can't find any articles comparing LEMP and the most popular configuration with LAMP and nginx as reverse proxy.

Thanks

Comment: LEMP includes NGINX, doesn't it? I thought that's what the 'E' was for (as silly as that may be). I don't think putting a full LEMP in front of a full LAMP makes sense, as you already have the linux, mysql, and php (L, M, and P). I think you want to do either LEMP or LAMP with nginx in front.

Comment: LEMP is Linux (L) NGIXN (E, due to EnGinx) MySQL (M), PHP (P)